Dynamically injecting content in thymeleaf

How to extend the layout.

I want to replace this line
<div th:replace="${content}"></div>



with the code of main.html.
My admin.html file
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html  xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Admin Page</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.8/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        /* Sidebar custom styling */
        .sidebar {
            background-color: #f8f9fa;
            padding: 20px;
            height: 100vh;
        }
        .sidebar a {
            color: #000;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: block;
            padding: 10px 0;
        }
        .sidebar a:hover {
            background-color: #e2e6ea;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <!-- Sidebar -->
            <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 sidebar">
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <li><a href="/">Main</a></li>
                    <li><a href="home">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="aboutus">About Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <!-- Main Content -->
            <div class="col-md-9 col-lg-10">
                <div th:fragment="content">
                    <div th:replace="${content}"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>

and main.html file is
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <body>

        <!-- Extend the layout.html and inject the home-content -->
        <div th:replace="layouts/admin :: content">
            <div th:fragment="homecontent">
                <div class="container">
                    <h1>Welcome to the Main Page</h1>
                    <p>This is the Main Page content area. You can place your website's content here.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>

If I go to main route like http://localhost:8080/

package com.groceryhub.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;



@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @GetMapping("")
    public String getMethodName() {
        return "admin/main/main";
    }
    

    @GetMapping("home")
    public String home() {
        return "admin/home/home";
    }
    
}

I am getting the below error:

Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions TemplateInputException: Error resolving fragment: "${content}": template or fragment could not be resolved (template: "layouts/admin" - line 44, col 26)


Do you want to use the thymeleaf-layout-dialect or just use Thymeleaf only?
